# Is this a good example for a question in Stackoverflow?

Tags: discussion, questions, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

Link: [What is a good method of doing TDD with legacy Delphi code having embedded SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18636503/what-is-a-good-method-of-doing-tdd-with-legacy-delphi-code-having-embedded-sql)

Please tell me because I just [failed a reopen audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/2890241) on it! :-)

Comment: If people upvote your question, do they agree that's a good question, or do they agree that it shouldn't have been an audit?

Comment: @DaveChen It's meta; nobody knows what votes mean here.  Try not to read into it too much if you value your sanity.

Comment: @DaveChen, you'll have to post that as question on meta(meta).stackexchange.com.

Comment: @Ferdinand.kraft Meta is its own meta.  Recursion FTW.

Comment: @Servy this is a concept beyond my understanding.

Comment: +1 because I agree with how you voted on your audit, -1 because I'm no longer sure what voting here means.

Comment: @DaveChen - Perhaps 7 people just like the [Rosette Nebula](http://goo.gl/lBZTbC).

Comment: @Cybȫʁgϟ37, so, if I had Angelina Jolie in my gravatar I'd have more upvotes?

Comment: @Ferdinand.kraft Who knows? Try it and lets find out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believed the purpose of audit questions is to correct "robo-reviewer" behaviour.  If that is true, then I don't think that was a good audit question.

A conscientious reviewer (which I believe you were) could decide that question should be closed.  Whether or not that close decision is considered correct, the point remains that you reached it by thoughtful deliberation.

It just seems wrong to me that you should be presented with a fail notice which screams at you to slow down and pay attention.  If your "leave closed" decision was actually wrong (I'm unconvinced about that), it was not because you were whipping through the queue too fast.  If audits are intended to discourage robo-reviews, the audit questions should be more clear-cut.

On the other hand, if audits are also intended to train us about nuances of close vote policy, then maybe it was a good audit question after all.  I would have failed that audit same as you.  That means I don't understand close vote policy well enough.  And that makes me conclude I should stop reviewing reopen and close votes.

Comment: Audits are [primarily intended to catch "robo-reviewers"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/171208/191410) and, thus, are *supposed* to be easy. That said, the questions are selected by a robo-reviewer-robo-reviewer which frequently selects questions which are not "easy" (i.e. "obvious"). While they may be useful for instruction, that is only meant as a by-product *after* being suspended for robo-reviewing.

Comment: I'm posting here also because it's not the first time I face such borderline cases; actually, the majority of audits I faced in the close and reopen queues are obscure like the one here.