# Why did I fail a Reopen Audit where there are 2 questions in a single post?

Tags: discussion, review, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

I just failed the audit on https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/2975172.

I voted "Leave Closed" because I don't believe the two questions are related enough to have in a single question.

Is this a proper audit question? If so, can someone please explain why this is a good post? Audits are generally much more clear-cut than this.

Comment: I hope you don't mind, I edited your question because "Bad Review Audit" is not a good question.  If you prefer it the way it was, please roll it back

Comment: I'd say that the two parts of the question are asking about different aspects of the overall question, which is roughly 'Why does `constexpr` have the limitations it does?' or 'Why is `constexpr` designed as it is?' and two separate questions would be answered with answers that duplicate large portions of the information.

Comment: audit item is not OK, as even the question asker [openly admits](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/18877057/3): "These should probably be in different questions..." - a downvote to the question, even unfortunately after the audit, would [at least ensure that next reviewer won't fall into this slippery trap](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/197484/165773 "as discussed eg here")

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would tend to agree with you. The post is borderline (I don't want to cast a close vote on it, but it's not wonderful either), mainly because it *is* asking two questions.

However, this post shouldn't have been an audit - as you say, audits should be more clear-cut. I would probably have failed too.

The system saw a post with +9 votes, and no close votes, and that's most of the audit selection criteria. Since computers aren't yet very good at reading comprehension, all they can go off of is votes.

Just shrug it off as a fundamental problem with computers that gets every reviewer at some point, and keep going.