# Disputed first post review audit

Tags: discussion, support, status-completed, disputed-review-audits

When looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/3306365), it looked to me like it belonged on Super User, as it was not asking about programming. However, when I tried to flag it, it was a known good audit and I failed it, causing me to be banned from reviewing for 7 days. Am I right or wrong in disputing this audit?

Comment: You got banned for just 1 failed review ?

Comment: @Habib Yes. I did.

Comment: That's not exactly the whole truth.  You were banned from reviews once before.  It's entirely possible that the trigger for banning you is more sensitive now.

Comment: Looks pretty off-topic to me...

Comment: @animuson: Can we lift the review ban?

Comment: @RobertHarvey But that first ban, which was for 2 days, was caused by just one failed review, wasn't it?

Comment: @gparyani: I can't tell.  SE is supposed to be in the process of improving the moderator tools for these things, so that we have better visibility.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I thought you were a Stack Exchange developer, so you could see these kinds of things.

Comment: No, I'm not a developer, just a diamond moderator.

Comment: Anyway, was I right in disputing this audit?

Comment: I closed the question.

Comment: This is yet another example illustrating the need for _improving_ review audit tests.

Comment: @devnull: I don't see how you can do that meaningfully with a machine.  The linked question is clearly off-topic, yet nobody bothered to vote to close it, and it has high upvotes.  The audit system picked the question because the community gave it an unambiguous stamp of approval.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Couldn't agree more. Sadly the community continues to give _unambiguous stamp of approval_ to such questions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's pretty clear that the question you linked is off-topic.  It got picked by the audit because several viewers upvoted it, and nobody bothered to cast a close vote.  Unfortunately, not everyone pays attention to the site rules, and the folks who visited this question were clearly only interested in its content, not the site rules.

Comment: Are audit questions selected automatically?! I thought they were hand-picked or at least reviewed.

Comment: They are selected automatically.  The question under discussion here would have never been picked by a human.

Comment: No wonder some of them are not good then :(

Comment: What is more baffling is that 1330 people visited that page, and they were *all* either unaware of the site scope, or couldn't be bothered to cast a flag or downvote.

Comment: @Szymon you might like http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/168374/147247

Comment: @KateGregory Very true. There should be some human selection into possible review audits. At the very least, there should be a "Dispute" button next to each failed review audit.