# It is possible to detect some audits - should it be?

Tags: discussion, review, review-audits

In my review queue this answer cropped up: [Why does Java allow us to compile a class with a name different than the file name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20195782/why-does-java-allow-us-to-compile-a-class-with-a-name-different-than-the-file-na/20208177#20208177)

I clicked `link` to view the answer in context and could see that it had 57 votes so I knew something was fishy (i.e. that this was likely an audit).

As it seemed fishy, I clicked `flag` out of curiosity which then triggered the failure message for me `"This was a high quality post"` (I wasn't actually going to continue with the flag as real flags take an extra step).

Anyway, my question is that why did the link show that it had 57 votes? Should this not be hidden from me if it is in my queue to prevent "cheating"?

Also the answer (and the debate on whether the analogy answers the question) in the is a bit of a toughie for a new reviewer to decide whether the analogy answers the question as it could just as easily be considered off topic.

Comment: No, it's been well discussed that if you take the extra step of investigating a post and notice the discrepancy, then you are paying enough attention and you aren't the people we are trying to target with the audits.

Comment: related to the Flag failing you bit: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/204598/why-does-pressing-the-flag-button-make-you-fail-an-audit

Comment: At a certain point trying to prevent the detection of audits starts to inhibit real reviewers; a line needs to be drawn somewhere.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Any comment on the answer in the audit... I notice you removed the `"disputed-review-audits"` tag - should I post this as a separate question?

Comment: @SilverlightFox I removed it because I thought your question was more about the detection and not about the disputed audit.  And you really weren't disputing the audit, just asking if this was a fair audit question.

Comment: @psubsee2003 That's cool - I've posted separately, I should not ask things that require separate answers like that in the same question.