# Review audit problem - whether answer answers question properly is subjective

Tags: support, disputed-review-audits

I have already posted this question: [It is possible to detect some audits - should it be?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210464/it-is-possible-to-detect-some-audits-should-it-be) but that was asking something in general rather than flagging a disputed review audit.

The answer that came up in my review queue was: [Why does Java allow us to compile a class with a name different than the file name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20195782/why-does-java-allow-us-to-compile-a-class-with-a-name-different-than-the-file-na/20208177#20208177)

Is this answer a bit of a toughie for a new reviewer to decide whether the analogy answers the question as it could just as easily be considered off topic?

Comment: When in doubt, Skip

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not being asked to see if the answer is a good answer to the question in the sense of technical accuracy. You are being asked if the answer is something like:

- I have this too did you solve it?
- Thanks everyone for your suggestions but they don't work for me
- Here's where to stream the football game / buy Gucci bags / meet Russian women
- But what about when the server is in the cloud?

If it looks like it's trying to answer the question, leave it. It might deserve downvotes from people who know whether it's a good analogy or not. If you can't tell it doesn't deserve one from you, and if it's trying it doesn't deserve a not-an-answer flag.

As an aside, that's a crummy question.

Comment: OK I now understand. I was trying to decide whether it was a flippant answer or not.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see a big problem with that audit question.  It is not a fantastic audit question because it is just an analogy and not a slam dunk like most should be, but if someone were to take the time to read the question and then look at the answer, it should be clear that it does answer the question.

> Is this answer a bit of a toughie for a new reviewer to decide whether the analogy answers the question as it could just as easily be considered off topic?

Yeah, it could be a toughie, but if they don't know, they shouldn't be reviewing the post and instead using the <kbd>Skip</kbd> button.  Just because you are shown a post in review doesn't mean you have to act on it (that's why "Skip" is there).

While not the intended function of the audits, there is some measure of teaching that comes out of it, so if a user doesn't perform the appropriate action a few times, they will eventually learn what constitutes a good post.

If you aren't aware, audits are selected automatically from recent posts based on the score (not just net score, but some queues also look at numbers of upvotes or downvotes), plus historical close votes and flags.  They aren't perfect, so occassionally you get the odd bad answer that is thought to be good, but more often than not, they are usually decent enough to perform the intended function.