# Looking for duplicate question via flag

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review, flags, review-audits

I was reviewing [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/3675926) and I thought : "Why not check if it has any duplicates?" I know the **flag "Duplicate"** question has **automatic search** function in the popup, so I pressed flag just to use that search function.
Immediately the review audit was failed as you can see. But it was not at all my intention to flag that question whatsoever.

Are there other users (reviewers) that use the flag "duplicate" for searching duplicates and also got a failed review audit while just trying to do a good reviewing job?

Is there a quicker way to search for duplicate questions? (I don't think so)

I know there aren't real repercussions to failing a [review audit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157121/what-are-review-tests-audits-and-how-do-they-work/157172#157172), but it isn't really motivating to see your audit failing by a click (on the link flag) that doesn't mean anything yet. So maybe this has to change?

UPDATE:

The important thing here for this site is to *reduce clutter* by removing duplicates. In my opinion this is something that could be improved in the reviewing process. A possibility is to show a list of possible duplicates immediately when you start reviewing an item (like in the flag - duplicate popup).

Comment: Closely related: [In the review queue, audits should only fail (or pass) you once you actually would take action](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212122/in-the-review-queue-audits-should-only-fail-or-pass-you-once-you-actually)

Comment: That's indeed closely related. But apart from the failed audit, my question was more oriented towards the finding of duplicates. This part could be improved in the reviewing section I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I never use the flag dialog to look for duplicates.  As a search mechanism, it stinks, at least compared to the other search options (like a site-specific search via Google and even the Stack Exchange search).

There aren't any faster ways though, but there are certainly more accurate ones.