# Showing votes on review audit questions

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, review-audits

I missed the upvote button on the First Post review and clicked the votes number instead (which was 0) and it displayed the real score of the audit answer.

[image]

I think this makes it pretty easy to cheat the audit, as it's one quick click, to find out what the correct response to pass it would be.

Comment: Audits are easy to cheat, by design. If one can spend that extra few seconds it means he's most likely not a robo reviewer anyway.

Comment: Related discussion here: [In the review queue, audits should only fail (or pass) you once you actually would take action](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/212122/157730)

Comment: @Shadow Not saying it's a game breaker but this just feels especially easy. If I was trying to spam through the reviews just to get a badge, I could easily just click the vote number for each question - it wouldn't even take a second.

Comment: @Amicable maybe, but there is also a user script that when installed will show you big alert "this is an audit". The dev team did not ban it and appears to be fine with it, so that's all the proof we need for my above point. If you care enough to do those tricks, you're not likely doing reviews just for badges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did your job - you spent at least a tiny effort to pass the audit.  They aren't designed to be very complex and serve only to give those people who are doing the same thing over and over some pause.  Beware, if we see abuse we may send you a few other test cases your way to make sure you're paying attention.