# Audits onset time make them easily detectable

Tags: bug, review, review-audits

There's a little break in the audit system.

It seems to require much time to generate and display an audit than to display a review. This is understandable, and I guess it mainly depends of the posts amount and our bandwidth, but it started to be easily detectable on SO a few weeks ago.

Each time I press <kbd>Next</kbd> and it tooks more than a second to display the new review, I'm 99% sure it's an audit.

Is this happening to many people ?

If so, it should be useful to try to reduce this time.

Comment: See the answer posted [to this related question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225870/showing-votes-on-review-audit-questions). Basically there are lots of ways to detect an audit. The staff are aware and they don't see it as an issue.

Comment: If you're paying enough attention to notice such delays, it means that you're paying attention.

Comment: @Robert does it mean you're paying attention to the right thing, or are you training some reviewers to spot clouds when you want them to spot tanks (ala https://neil.fraser.name/writing/tank/ )?