# Close question review audits should "pass" faster

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, review-audits

I was given a review audit for the close queue, and I had to

1. Click the close button
2. Choose the "off topic" radio button
3. Click the "Vote to close" button

For a closeworthy question as an audit, clicking the "Close" button ought to suffice.

If it's a question that ought to stay open, I understand that going through the full process should happen before you "fail", as per [In the review queue, audits should only fail (or pass) you once you actually would take action](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212122/in-the-review-queue-audits-should-only-fail-or-pass-you-once-you-actually-wou)

Comment: What if you only clicked _Close_ to see the distribution of existing votes over the reasons?

Comment: @chirlu at least that'd indicate you weren't robo-reviewing.

Comment: Close, cancel, keep open, rinse and repeat?