# Why is this question on topic?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, review-audits

I just hit an audit and failed (for my first time) and I'm wondering why.

Its this question: [Detect and Log copy/paste/delete/cut operations in File Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21968828/detect-and-log-copy-paste-delete-cut-operations-in-file-explorer) in where the question is:

```
Is there something better than the `FileSystemWatcher`?
```

I would have thought that this is off-topic - looking for a favorite offsite resource / library.

Comment: Agreed. And it has an open bounty, I cannot vote to close it.

Comment: It's "on-topic" for the sake of the audit, because it only looks at the score and open/closed status as an indicator. But of course, that's only from the audit's point of view.

Comment: Relevant: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168374/bring-a-human-factor-into-review-audit-composition-selection  (general answer: it's not, but the lots of upvotes and no downvotes or close votes metric makes the system think it's a good question.  And people ask me why I have so many downvotes--if people weren't so reluctant to downvote, we wouldn't have bad audits.)

Comment: @Bart The audit is an automated system? I would have thought that the reasons for it be more "precise" like a Dimond must have said that its on-topic or such.

Comment: Nope -- it's completely automated, which has caused a few dubious audits. Check out some of the questions in the `[review-audits]` tag: some of the audits are rather egregious.

Comment: I'm just hoping that the OP of that question doesn't come to Meta asking clarification about a sudden surge of downvotes on one particular question.

Comment: Well the OP is here , and don't understand why is it off-topic since I wrote down in my question that `FileSystemWatcher` is not satisfy my needs. Since it just cant to give me the desired information.
and I am looking for something ELSE that would .

Comment: @Roma-MT Well, the general idea here is that asking for a recommendation for something is off topic here. http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic Whatever the reasons are why you are looking for it is not so relevant. (While I personally disagree with this, its the rules. You may want to craft a great question on softwarerecs.stackexchange.com but what you have until now wouldn't fit.)

Comment: @Roma-MT you can flag the post, and a mod might refund your bounty and close the question.  But I also like the earlier suggestion for [SR.SE](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).  There are some [specific guidelines](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/questions/13031/laying-some-ground-rules-for-software-recommendations) for asking questions to make it on-topic, but I think you'd definately have better luck getting a good answer there.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Ok I will try my luck there thanks.

Comment: @Roma-MT just make sure you explain exactly what you want, why `FileSystemWatcher` doesn't suit your needs, and any other requirements.

Comment: @psubsee2003: I think the question contains exactly that. "I have read about `FileSystemWatcher`, but I also noticed it has some issues since there is no copy/cut there is create file". From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx): *The operating system and FileSystemWatcher object interpret a cut-and-paste action or a move action as a rename action for a folder and its contents.*

Comment: @psubsee2003 current meta link for those requirements - [What is required for a question to contain “enough information”?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I must say I disagree with closing this question. While at first sight it might look like a resource request, in its essence it's just the same as

> "I've been trying to watch changes in the filesystem but the `FileSystemWatcher` does not support copy/cut actions. Is it possible to get notified for these actions?"

Yes, he explicitly asks if something else might provide this functionality but that is hardly an 'offsite resource'.

Why are you interpreting this as a software recommendation? Nowhere is it mentioned and it definitely shouldn't be interpreted as such, otherwise there is a lot of closing to do every minute.

When somebody asks a question about how to display a timespan of just H:m:s and tells us he "tried `DateTime` but this didn't suffice", would you also close the question purely because his next line was "Is there something else than `DateTime` that allows us to display a timespan"?

This rule was designed to avoid people littering the answer section with recommendations for libraries, books, etc, not to close questions from people who clearly state what the (known) downside is of a commonly used class and ask for alternatives.

Comment: Why not edit the question to be clear in what it's asking then?  This is a collaboratively edited site that places an emphasis on clarity of questions and answers, after all.  Also, note it wasn't closed because it was asking for recommendations, it was closed because it was subjective in asking "for something better". **TL;DR** Edit it into shape, vote/flag for it to be reopened.  This is the cycle of things on SO.

Comment: @casperOne then I would ask for advice -> should I edit the question?
or just better to delete it (I can't,maybe you can ?) and make a question as suggested above on SR.SE ?

Comment: @Roma-MT I'd suggest editing it.  Closure isn't a big deal on SO.  We reopen things all the time and it's certainly not the mark of shame that people think it is (even though we transitioned to "on hold" to try and alleviate that misconception).

Comment: Because I never considered the question to be unclear. I agree that there is some noise in there but none of that masked the intent of the asker. I do plenty of edits everywhere, that's not a problem. What I do see is several people advocating to close it when it should have just been edited to remove fluff, not because the question was unclear.

Comment: @casperOne OK , I will try my best editing it to fit the Rules ,but it will take some time for me. 
Still the question isn't answered for a long time and I honestly lost a hope for it being answered.

Comment: @Roma-MT: I have edited your post in the meanwhile, it should be fine now.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel WoW you did it really nice , I doubt I could do it myself , Thank you very much !

Comment: @casperOne Once I got question closed and I couldn't ask any more questions after wards it was said that SO doesn't accept questions from me , so I just don't want it to happen again .