# Should this question be kept open or closed?

Tags: support, review, vote-to-close, disputed-review-audits

[How can I quickly and easily configure GHC integration for Emacs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22296676/is-there-a-ghc-integration-for-emacs-that-just-works)

[image]

Asking because it was an audit for me in the close vote review queue. I clicked close and failed the audit. I don't fail many audits, so when I do, I'd like to know where I went wrong or if the system just made a mistake.

***EDIT 3/13/2014*** : The question ended up being closed as primarily opinion-based.

***EDIT 3/13/2014*** : The question has been re-opened by five people voting to re-open it.

Comment: Why do *you* think it should be closed, if you feel so strongly that it should be?

Comment: I don't have any particular reason to think it *should* be closed, but then again I don't have much/any experience with Haskell or Emacs - so perhaps there's some terrible subtlety I'm missing? Anyway, I edited the title - maybe now you can explain why you thought it *should* be closed instead of just letting it dangle here like a corpse on the gallows...

Comment: I don't *think* either of those applies... Unless, as I said, there's something about Emacs that makes this the equivalent of "what color should my text be?" But the answers don't really back that up.

Comment: It helps to skip reviews in subjects where you lack knowledge.

Comment: I think it probably should be, as it creates opinionated answers (almost all the time).

Comment: just... [Bring a “human factor” into review audit composition/selection](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/197484/165773 "do as explained here, to ensure that next reviewer won't fall into this trap")

Comment: I've used Emacs since the early 90s. "Is there a GHC integration for Emacs that just works?" reads like someone who is asking the people at SO to suggest an Emacs mode, which in my book is a "favorite off-site resource". The body of the question also states "perhaps installing some package from Hackage." I understand Hackage is a collection of packages for Haskell. So both on the Emacs side and the Haskell side, this question invites suggestions for "off-site resource[s]".

Comment: I voted reopen, because Emacs.

Comment: reopen likely won't get it back to audits (hope the algorithm is smart enough to account for having closure in question history), especially since it managed to get 3 downvotes along the way. Mission accomplished, reviewers won't slip on this banana skin anymore

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Emacs is a console-based text editor. It is known for seeming simple and actually being sometimes hard to work with. GHC (Glasgow Haskell Compiler) is a compiler for Emacs that has certain features that are valuable, which the OP mentioned.

Emacs is also popular among programmers, but it is apparently hard to find other code that integrates seamlessly without doing a bunch of work to get it to be perfect.

It seems that this problem of trying to get GHC in Emacs is shared by lots of people. It is about "[a] software tool commonly used by programmers", so I wouldn't say it is off topic.

---

All in all, I would chalk this up to being out of your area of expertise. I sometimes take crack shots at areas that are outside of my expertise, but only on answers and never in review queues.

Also, if something seems bad about a question, and it doesn't fall into any of the close vote categories, then just downvote. No need to create an issue if there isn't one in the first place.

Comment: Yup, no problem. See you around!